# Where chef store the gem source repository?

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra, chef-solo

I am using Chef-solo for my provision infrastructure.

Well I was interested in change the chef gem source repository to my local repository. I did it with these commands:

```bash
/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem sources -r http://rubygems.org/

/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem sources -a http://gems.localserver/
```

But now I want to know:

Where chef put its **current gem source**??

Is there something like a **.gemrc** for chef?

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't modify anything inside of `/opt/chef`. That belongs to Chef and changing things in that directory "voids" your install.

Comment: I do not have internet access or is very restricted in many times and then I need that chef load the gems from my local repository... how can I do that..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the gem inside `/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem` to install things, it stores them by default on the local file system in

`/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems`

As to whether using this gem utility is wise or not, @sethvargo certainly knows more about chef than me, but I've been using it to install "chef" related things like test-kitchen and so far so good.

You certainly need to be a bit careful with this since you can easily break chef with the wrong gems. But it's very handy to have a single ruby path with all the chef goodies installed for testing and development.

Answer (score 3):

the gemrc for chefs embedded gem is /opt/chef/embedded/etc/gemrc

Comment: I'd +1 this 100 times if I could. I'd been trying to figure out why Chef wasn't picking up /etc/gemrc. Thanks!